# Show that $\int^{x+p}_{x}f(t)dt$ is independent of x in that, for all x and y, $\int^{x+p}_{x}f(t)dt=\int^{y+p}_{y}f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and has period $p$, so that
$$f(x+p)=f(x)  \text{ for all }x \in \mathbb R$$
Show that $$\int^{x+p}_{x}f(t)dt$$ is independent of $x$ in that, for all $x$ and $y$, $\int^{x+p}_{x}f(t)dt=\int^{y+p}_{y}f(t)dt$

Show then, that $$\int^{p}_{0}[f(x+a)-f(x)]dx=0$$
for any real number $a$. Conclcude that for any real number $a$, there is $x$ such that $f(x+a)=f(x)$

This chapter has been extrememly confusing for me in my analysis class and I need help. So far this is all I have written down for this problem.

ok, so we have $f: R \to R$ with $f(x+p)=f(x)$ and we need to show $\int^{x+p}_{x}f(t)dt=\int^{y+p}_{y}f(t)dt$

So I can state $f(t+p)=F(t)$ and $\int^{p}_{0}f(t+p)dt=\int^{p}_{0}f(t)dt$

We need to take the derivative of $$\left[\int^{x+p}_{x}f(t)dt\right]^1_y=\left[
\int^{y+p}_{y}f(t)dt\right]^1_y$$

$f(x+p)-f(x)=f(y+p)-f(y)$

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that given $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there holds
$$
\int_x^{x+p} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{p} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$
Try first proving this if $x$ is a multiple of $p$ by using the change of variable $s = t - x$. Note that if $x$ is a multiple of $p$ then $f(s) = f(t+x) = f(t)$.

If $x$ is not a multiple of $p$, observe that the interval $(x,x+p)$ must contain a product of $p$. Let $y\in (x, x+p)$ be this multiple of $p$. Once again using a change of variables, you can show that
$$
\int_y^{x+p} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{x-y+p} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
and
$$
\int_x^{y} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_{x-y+p}^{p} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$